# $A\rtimes B$ vs $B\rtimes A$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

What is the difference between $A\rtimes B$ and $B\rtimes A$?

Could one group be normal in a group $G$ and at the same time not normal in another group?

The asymmetry of the $\rtimes$ symbol (with or without a specified action) suggests that $A$ and $B$ aren't quite interchangeable in the semi-direct product construction, so it is natural to wonder whether both $A\rtimes B$ and $B\rtimes A$ make sense for any given pair of groups $A$ and $B$ and, if so, whether there is any relationship between the two.

Comment: Recall that the [semi-direct product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product) $G \rtimes H$ is defined via a homomorphism $\varphi: H \to \operatorname{Aut}(G)$. You can't form the semidirect product of an arbitrary pair of groups, since $\varphi$ needn't exist. Moreover, different maps from $H$ to $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ may give non-isomorphic groups, so you need to specify your homomorphism. Coming back to your question, a semidirect product $B \rtimes A$ need not exist even if $A \rtimes B$ *does* exist, so in general it doesn't make sense to try to compare them.

Comment: @MorganO For any $G$ and $H$, the map $\phi:H \to {\rm Aut}(G)$ with $\phi(h)$ equal to the identity for all $h$ exists, so you can form a semidirect product of any two groups: i.e. the direct product.

Comment: Why the down votes? This seems to be a reasonable question for someone at a certain level of understanding which @MorganO has addressed nicely in a comment.

Comment: @DerekHolt you are of course correct. Too late to edit, but I should have been more careful and specified "non-trivial semidirect products", meaning ones via a non-trivial homomorphism, or something like this.

Comment: The asymmetry is to indicate that you have an action of one of the groups on the other. The action of one group on another need not give the same result in the opposite order (even up to isomorphism).

Comment: Do you know what is the semidirect product? It seems from what you say that you only know the symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding/correcting my comment...

Recall that the [semidirect product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product) $G \rtimes_\varphi H$ is defined via a homomorphism $\varphi: H \to \operatorname{Aut}(G)$. The underlying set of the semidirect product is [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) $G \times H$, and multiplication $*$ is defined by

$$(a,b)*(c,d)=(a\varphi_b(c),bd),$$ where $\varphi_b$ abbreviates the automorphism $\varphi(b)$. Different homomorphisms $\varphi$ may give non-isomorphic groups, so you need to specify your homomorphism. Just writing $G \rtimes H$ is ambiguous (although on occasion it might be an appropriate shorthand).

As Derek Holt points out in the comments, the semidirect product associated to the  trivial homomorphism exists for any $G$ and $H$. By trivial, I mean $\epsilon:H \to \operatorname{Aut}(G)$ where $\epsilon_h:G\to G$ is the identity of $G$ for each $h \in H$. In this case we recover the direct sum $G \oplus H$:

$$(g_1,h_1) * (g_2,h_2) =(g_1\epsilon_{h_1}(g_2),h_1h_2)=(g_1g_2,h_1h_2).$$

So we can always arrange that $A\rtimes_\varphi B \simeq B \rtimes_\psi A$ (by taking trivial homomorphisms for both). For general $\varphi$ and $\psi$:

- Both semidirect products contain $A$ and $B$ as subgroups: $A\simeq A \times \{e_B\} $, and $B\simeq \{e_A\} \times B$.
- For $A$ and $B$ finite, $|A\rtimes_\varphi B|=|B\rtimes_\psi A|=|A|\cdot |B|$: this is the size of the underlying set.

Beyond this, structures of $A \rtimes_\phi B$ and $B\rtimes_\psi A$ **depend on the given maps.** The two needn't be isomorphic; in fact, $A \rtimes_\varphi B$ needn't be isomorphic to $B \rtimes_\alpha A$ for *any* choice of $\alpha: A \to \operatorname{Aut}(B)$.

For an **example** of this, let $A=\mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z$, $B=\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$. We can identify $B$ with the set $\{1,2,4\}$ under *multiplication* modulo $7$ (check this). Define $\varphi:B \to \operatorname{Aut}(A)$ by

$$\varphi_i([x])=[ix],$$ where $[y]$ is the class of an integer $y$ in $\mathbb Z / 7 \mathbb Z$ (verify this is well-defined). This group is non-abelian:

$$([3],2)*([2],1)=([3]\cdot \varphi_2([2]),2)=([3]\cdot[4],2)=([5],2),$$

while

$$([2],1)*([3],2)=([2]\cdot \varphi_1([3]),2)=([2]\cdot[3],2)=([6],2).$$

So we see that $a*b \neq b*a$ for some $a,b \in A \rtimes_\varphi B$. On the other hand, $|\operatorname{Aut}(B)|=2$; by order considerations, the only homomorphism $\alpha:A \to \operatorname{Aut}(B)$ is trivial. In particular, $B \rtimes_\alpha A \simeq B \oplus A$ is abelian, and not isomorphic to $A \rtimes_\varphi B$.

---

I take your second question to be about whether $B$ can be normal in $A \rtimes_\varphi B$, as well as $B\rtimes_\psi A$. $B$ is *always* normal in the latter, but "rarely" in the former. You can verify that $$(a,b)^{-1}=(\varphi_{b^{-1}}(a^{-1}),b^{-1}),$$ and that

$$(a,b)*(c,d)*(a,b)^{-1}=(a\varphi_{b}(c)\varphi_{bdb^{-1}}(a^{-1}),bdb^{-1}).$$

This implies that $ A \times \{e_B\} \rhd A \rtimes_\varphi B$: if $d=e_B$, the right hand side is in $A \times \{e_B\}$ for any $(a,b)$. On the other hand, $\{e_A\}\times B$ isn't necessarily stable under conjugation:

$$(a,b)*(e_A,d)*(a,b)^{-1}=(a\varphi_{b}(e_A)\varphi_{bdb^{-1}}(a^{-1}),bdb^{-1})=(a\varphi_{bdb^{-1}}(a^{-1}),bdb^{-1}).$$

This element lies in $\{e_A\} \times B$ if and only if $\varphi_{bdb^{-1}}(a^{-1})=a^{-1}$. Since this must hold for any choice of $a,b,d$, this implies $\varphi_{x}=\mathbb 1_A$ for any $x\in B$. Thus, $B \lhd A \rtimes_\varphi B$ *if and only if* $\varphi$ is trivial.